# mysql joining 3 tables with a group by group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have three tables

```
users:

+----+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | user_type_id |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Tawsif |            1 |
|  2 | Karim  |            2 |
+----+--------+--------------+
transactions:
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | amount |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |     10 |
|  2 |       2 |     10 |
|  3 |       1 |     10 |
+----+---------+--------+
course_fee:
+----+---------+-----+
| id | user_id | fee |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 |       1 | 105 |
|  2 |       2 |  33 |
|  3 |       1 | 106 |
+----+---------+-----+
```

I want to get the count of total_rows, sum of each users transaction amount and fees from both transactions and course fees table

So I tried this

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(transactions.amount) as total_transaction_amount,
count(transactions.id) as transaction_count, 
sum(course_fee.fee) as total_fee, 
count(course_fee.user_id) as total_fee_count 
    FROM users 
INNER join transactions on transactions.user_id = users.id 
INNER join course_fee on course_fee.user_id = users.id 
    GROUP by users.id
```

result:

```
+----+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | total_transaction_amount | transaction_count | total_fee | total_fee_count |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|  1 |                       40 |                 4 |       422 |               4 |
|  2 |                       10 |                 1 |        33 |               1 |
+----+----------
```

It returned Wrong results. How can i Fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a common problem occurring when trying to report aggregates from multiple tables related by a join.  One sane way of handling this is to join to two separate subqueries, each of which aggregates transactions and fees separately:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    COALESCE(t.amount, 0) AS total_transaction_amount,
    COALESCE(t.cnt, 0)    AS transaction_count,
    COALESCE(c.fee, 0)    AS total_fee,
    COALESCE(c.cnt, 0)    AS total_fee_count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
    ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(fee) AS fee
    FROM course_fee
    GROUP BY user_id
) c
    ON u.id = c.user_id;
```

Note that we left join above because perchance a user does not appear in either the transaction or fee tables.  In that case, we assign a value of zero to the sums and counts.

Comment: My answer _is_ a join query.  Not sure what you have in mind.

Comment: oops sorry ... i was so tired while checking stackoverflow.. thanks again anyway

Answer (score 1):

Correct Ans

```
   SELECT test.id,transaction_count,test.total_transaction_amount, 
    IFNULL(SUM(course_fee.fee),0) AS total_fee, 
    IFNULL(COUNT(course_fee.user_id),0) AS total_fee_count  FROM 
    (
      SELECT users.id, IFNULL(SUM(transactions.amount),0) AS 
      total_transaction_amount,
      IFNULL(COUNT(transactions.id),0) AS transaction_count
      FROM users 
      LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.user_id = users.id 
      GROUP BY users.id
    ) AS test 
    LEFT JOIN course_fee ON course_fee.user_id = test.id 
    GROUP BY test.id
```

**This is what happening in your query after `2nd JOIN` that's why you are getting 40 for id 1**

[image]